# How to retrieve body string of request generated by scala-dispatch

Tags: scala, http, scala-dispatch

I have a request generated by putting map of parameters

```
  val reqUrl = url("http://example.com")
  val req = reqUrl << Map("key" -> "value")
```

I need to get request body in order to calculate it's hash. I'm trying this way

```
  val data = req.toRequest.getStringData

  println(data)
```

but it results `null`.

Answer (score 3):

The `request` you currently defined is a `GET` request which normally has no body. So `null` is the expected body value.

You could try using a `POST` as described here : http://dispatch.databinder.net/HTTP+methods+and+parameters.html.

```
val reqUrl = url("http://example.com")
val postReq = reqUrl.POST
val req = postReq << Map("key" -> "value")
req.toRequest.getStringData
```

Comment: I think it's not what i need. I need request body before it's sent. Not response.

Comment: Rewrote the answer to match your requirements.